# Comparison Operators

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison, operators

Reffer [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

I know operand with string type translate to number, and then usual math

But see these sample codes:

```
echo intval(1e1);       // 10
var_dump("1e1" == 10);  // true, and it's ok

echo intval(0x1A);      // 26
var_dump("0x1A" == 26); // true, and it's ok

echo intval(042);       // 34
var_dump("042" == 34);  // fasle, Why ?!!!
```

Why last code return false.

Comment: `var_dump(intval(042) == 34);` works peachy

Comment: [Types matter](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WM1kgX)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because string-to-number conversion in PHP is based on some ancient C function - `strtod`. And its rules are as [follows](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtod.3.html):

> The expected form of the (initial portion of the) string is optional
>   leading white space as recognized by isspace(3), an optional plus
>   ('+') or minus sign ('-') and then either (i) a decimal number, or
>   (ii) a hexadecimal number [...]
>
> A decimal number consists of a nonempty sequence of decimal digits
>   possibly containing a radix character (decimal point,
>   locale-dependent, usually '.'), optionally followed by a decimal
>   exponent.  A decimal exponent consists of an 'E' or 'e', followed by
>   an optional plus or minus sign, followed by a nonempty sequence of
>   decimal digits, and indicates multiplication by a power of 10. [... ]
>
> A hexadecimal number consists of a "0x" or "0X" followed by a nonempty
>   sequence of hexadecimal digits possibly containing a radix character,
>   optionally followed by a binary exponent. [...]

As you see, '1e1' string has non-empty sequence '1' followed by a decimal exponent 'e1'. So, it will be converted into a decimal number - and becomes 10.

'0x1A' string follows the rules for hexadecimal number, and will be converted into 26 accordingly. But as there's no specific rule for octadecimal number, '042' will be converted into a plain decimal - and becomes 42. Which is, of course, not equal to 34.

This should not be confused with how *number* literals are parsed by PHP itself. A number literal that starts with 0 is considered representing an octadecimal. So, `intval(042)` is essentially the same as `intval(34)` - but not the same as `intval("042")`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. That means that binary literals are not correctly converted either.

Comment: It's nice to see some sort of actual reason and a proper explanation put into an answer for once, +1.

Answer (score 3):

That's how `PHP` rolls. It is because when you specify a string and convert, it gets converted to a number, In your case, the first `1e1` means `1 exponent 1`, the `0x1A` is hexadecimal representation and final part `042` itself is a number and it is converted to `42` but `intval(042)` means octal representation of integer 34.

Comment: I think the real question here is: why does the implicit conversion respect base 16 (denoted by the string beginning with 0x), but does NOT respect base 8 (denoted by the string beginning with  leading zero)?

Comment: @rodion Because PHP is annoying and inconsistent. There will be some nonsense reason for it buried deep in the sands of PHP/FI I'm sure.

Comment: Because I think so many people would be confused and filing bugs on why "042" != 42. With 0x and e it is clear on what it is doing.

Comment: @Kris Well that would be their fault for not reading the docs. And you don't get people filing bugs asking about octal literals (I don't know, maybe you do, but they will just be told to RTFM). No matter how you look at it, as long as you pick a standard and stick to it it's fine, and the standard that they have *not* stuck to is "strings are converted like source code literals are interpreted". If you were worried about `"042"` you could just `intval(ltrim("042", "0"))` to guarantee decimal.

Comment: @rodion It is just the way `PHP` works. when you specify a number with no strings in it it is a `NUMBER` when you `var_dump()` it!! If you had mixups it will look try to convert from `hex` or `exp` or wat ever the closest match is.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I don't consider an answer "that's because it's PHP, you know" neither complete nor helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all the math mumbo jumbo but,

Because the first two examples are clear what you are trying to do.. convert it to an exponent, and convert it to hex. 
But the third solution is not clear on what you are doing, so it converts it to 42. 
Think about it the other way..
You are trying to solvve a problem and for some reason "042" does not equal 42. you would be very confused

So use what you need, if you need an int representation of 042 then cast to an int, but if it is a string don't expect it to work that way.

Comment: Yes but in that case it is clear you are doing octal notation since you are prefacing it with a zero. I think it is easy to understand, if you want an integer value cast it to an int, if you dont leave it a string.